# how to search a value from table in Laravel

Tags: php, validation, laravel

I am trying to search a value from database table and display result to web site using laravel. my controller.php code is here

```
else
      { 
       try
       {
          $pname = Input::get('pname');
          $parents = ForumParent::where('pname', $pname)->first();           
         if(empty($parents))
          {
            throw new  \Exception("Parent not found");}           
            return Redirect::route('view',$parents->paddress);     
          }
       catch (Exception $e)
          { return "not value";        
             //abort(404);
          } 
        }
      }
public function view($paddress)
{  
   $parents=ForumParent::find($paddress);
   $users=User::all();
   return View::make('search.viewsearch')
   ->with('parents',$parents)
   ->with('users',$users);
}
```

Comment: Could you care to explain yourself better? Since you are already searching for a value here `$parents=ForumParent::find($paddress);`

Comment: my routes.php is this Route::group(array('prefix' =>'/search'),function()
{
  Route::get('/', array('uses'=>'SearchController@getSearch','as'=>'getSearch'));
  Route::post('/', array('uses'=>'SearchController@postSearch','as'=>'postSearch'));
  Route::get('/search/viewsearch/{pname}',array('uses'=>'SearchController@view','as'=>'view'));

Comment: my viewsearch.blade.php page is this .....@foreach($parents as $parent)
   {{$parent->pmobile}}

 
      <h5 class="list-group-item">
    {{$parent->paddress}}
     <input type="hidden" name="id" id="id" value="{{$parent->id}}">.my problem is when im enter a value (if it present in database)
ErrorException (E_UNKNOWN)

Invalid argument supplied for foreach() (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\lara3\lara3\app\views\search\viewsearch.blade.php)
this error msg occur...but the else part is working...

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
$parents = ForumParent::where('pname', $pname)->first();
```

to this:

```
$parents = ForumParent::where('pname', '=', $pname)->first();
```

**OR**

```
$parents = ForumParent::where('pname','LIKE', '%' . $pname . '%')->first();
```

See, if that helps.

Comment: i use...$parents = ForumParent::where('pname','LIKE', '%' . $pname . '%')->first(); and $parents = ForumParent::where('pname', '=', $pname)->first(); but  still same error...
ErrorException (E_UNKNOWN)

Invalid argument supplied for foreach() (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\lara3\lara3\app\views\search\viewsearch.blade.php)
ithink its viewsearch.lade.php  page problem ...my viewsearch .blade.php page is.@foreach($parents as $parent)
{{$parent->pmobile}}
 {{$parent->paddress}}
     <input type="hidden" name="id" id="id" value="{{$parent->pname}}">.and my routes.php is this.....

Comment: Route::group(array('prefix' =>'/search'),function()
{
  Route::get('/', array('uses'=>'SearchController@getSearch','as'=>'getSearch'));
  Route::post('/', array('uses'=>'SearchController@postSearch','as'=>'postSearch'));
 
  Route::group(array('before' =>'auth'),function()
 {
   Route::get('/search/viewsearch/{pname}',array('uses'=>'SearchController@viewsearch','as'=>'viewsearch'));
  });
});
  Sorry  iam new in laravel....so i dont know howto deal with this types of errors..

Comment: Are you able to see pname's value? when accessing through url

Comment: yes ..iam enter name is "ammu" after run URL get http://localhost/lara3/lara3/public/search/search/viewsearch/ammufhgfhgf%20hfg." is my paddress in database----ammufhgfhgf hfg".

Comment: instead of adding your routes and view file to comment, add them to your question. So, that it will be more clear

Comment: my routes.php is..........Route::group(array('prefix' =>'/search'),function()
{
  Route::get('/', array('uses'=>'SearchController@getSearch','as'=>'getSearch'));
  Route::post('/', array('uses'=>'SearchController@postSearch','as'=>'postSearch'));
 
  Route::group(array('before' =>'auth'),function()
 {
   Route::get('/search/viewsearch/{pname}',array('uses'=>'SearchController@viewsearch','as'=>'viewsearch'));
  });
});
  viewsearch.blade.php is.............@foreach($parents as $parent)
{{$parent->pmobile}}
 {{$parent->paddress}}
<input type="hidden" name="id" id="id" value="{{$parent->pname}}">

Comment: Have you added my suggested code in your controller? try to print $parents as print_r($parents). and what error are you getting? parent no found or not value?

Comment: .iam enter name iin textbox "ammu" and submit . after run URL get localhost/lara3/lara3/public/search/search/viewsearch/…; is my paddress in database----ammufhgfhgf hfg". bt the problem is not execute viewsearch.blad.php. they have an error is.
ErrorException (E_UNKNOWN)

Invalid argument supplied for foreach() (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\lara3\lara3\app\views\search\viewsearch.blade.php)
i think foreach loop is problem...can you give right code for viewsearch.blade.php and routes.

Comment: Add output of print_r($parents) in your question

Comment: no error msg.and no parent details.nothing... im trying like this     $pname = Input::get('pname');
             $parents = ForumParent::where('pname', '=', $pname)->first();
                //print_r($parents);    
             if(empty($parents))
              {
                   print_r($parents);    
                // throw new  \Exception("Parent not found");}           
                // return Redirect::route('viewsearch',$parents->paddress);     
              }

Comment: try to add exit after print_r statement.

Comment: try exit after print_r statement.  i got error msg is 
ErrorException (E_UNKNOWN)

Invalid argument supplied for foreach() (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\lara3\lara3\app\views\search\viewsearch.blade.php)
and also got URL paddress  that is...http://localhost/lara3/lara3/public/search/search/viewsearch/ammufhgfhgf%20hfg im enter value is " ammu" and ammu's address is "ammufhgfhgf hfg "